# Vue.js - Component and Element.io - error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I use this Component from Element.io: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover

in my template:

```
<div id="app">
    <el-tabs>
        <el-tab-pane v-for="(shop, index) in shops" v-bind:label="shop.shopName">
             <jett-settings :shop="shop" inline-template>
                <div>
                    <el-popover
                            ref="popover1"
                            placement="top-start"
                            title="Title"
                            width="200"
                            trigger="click"
                            content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
                    </el-popover>

                    <el-button v-popover:popover1>Hover to activate</el-button>

                </div>
            </jett-settings>
        </el-tab-pane>
    </el-tabs>
</div>
```

The Vue.js part looks like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['%%', '%%'],
    el: '#app',
    ...
```

And the component:

```
Vue.component('jettSettings', {
    props: ['shop'],
    ....
```

And I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in directive popover bind hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'reference' of undefined"
```

Does somebody know why this error occurs and how I can solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: share all code with live demo, there is not `reference` in your code

Comment: @user2486 - In my whole template there is no "reference". The only reference I have is the ref="popover1" in the <el-popover element.

Comment: try to put `el-popover` inside `jett-settings` component  not inside tag as in example

Comment: You mean above the <div>? It does not work, then I get: "Inline-template components must have exactly one child element.". In my example I forgot something important, the v-for. I edited it. Can that be the reason?

Comment: @Toben :  You put tag inside tag, just imagine that outer tag is replace by template then inner tag will not work.

Comment: Do you have an example? I do not understand what you are saying :/

Comment: Can you share a live demo of your code ?

Comment: Yes: https://jsfiddle.net/8po71jp0/ Here I get the same error in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that binding ref to a variable is not supported by vue. the way to get around it is to wrap the functionality as a separate component

```js
// register
Vue.component('my-popover', {
  template: `<div>
  <el-popover
        ref="dynamic"
        placement="top-start"
        :title="shop"
        width="200"
        trigger="hover">
        this is content, this is content for {{shop}, this is content
      </el-popover>
      <el-button v-popover:dynamic >Hover to activate</el-button>
  </div>`,
  props: ['shop']
})

var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      shops: ['abc', 'def']
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-tabs>
    <el-tab-pane v-for="(shop, index) in shops" v-bind:label="shop">
    <my-popover :shop=shop></my-popover>
    </el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works now. I have question left: http://d.pr/i/K8hNRE Why is the shop printed here? :shop="shop" seems to result in echoing the shop - but why?

Comment: shop is the string in your array the that is bound to the shop prop in the component. you can rename it to title, like I did here https://jsfiddle.net/h178j5Lg/1/

Comment: also, `:<propname>` is shor-hand for `v-bind:<propname>`  for example: `<my-popover :shop=shop></my-popover>` and `<my-popover v-bind:shop=shop></my-popover>` are the same